# QuickTime plugin for Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser-addons, quicktime

I'm using Firefox 3.6.3 on Win 7 x64. Some web sites require QuickTime plugin. How can I install Firefox QuickTime plugin without installing [Apple's QuickTime](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/)? I definitely don't want to install QuickTime to my system.

Comment: This is an EXCELLENT question. The real QuickTime, like so much of Apple's software, is bloated beyond extreme!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [QT Lite](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/QT_Lite.htm).

> QT Lite is a trimmed down version of
>   QuickTime that contains only the
>   essential components needed for
>   playing QuickTime content that is
>   embedded in web pages.

Comment: will this work for Chrome?

Comment: @decio-lira: Yes it does: `Changelog 2.6.0 to 2.6.2 ~ 2008-09-08 Now supports the Google Chrome web browser`